# Can I use multiprocessing.Pool in a method of a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am tring to use `multiprocessing` in my code for better performance.

However, I got an error as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\EpubBuilder\TinyEpub.py", line 49, in <module>
    e.epub2txt()
  File "D:\EpubBuilder\TinyEpub.py", line 43, in epub2txt
    tempread = self.get_text()
  File "D:\EpubBuilder\TinyEpub.py", line 29, in get_text
    txtlist = pool.map(self.char2text,charlist)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 383, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 50, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.BufferedReader' object
```

I have tried it an other way and got this error:

```
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

My code looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.namelist = arg
    def format_char(self,char):
        char = char + "a"
        return char
    def format_book(self):
        self.tempread = ""
        charlist = [f.read() for f in self.namelist] #list of char
        with Pool() as pool:
            txtlist = pool.map(self.format_char,charlist)
        self.tempread = "".join(txtlist)
        return self.tempread

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import os
    b = Book([open(f) for f in os.listdir()])
    t = b.format_book()
    print(t)
```

I think that the error is raised because of not using the `Pool` in the main function.

Is my conjecture right? And how can I modify my code to fix the error?

Comment: What does `type(charlist[0])` say?  And it's a bit confusing because your error message does not match the code you posted. (`char2text` vs. `format_char`).

Comment: @JohnZwinck My real code is quite long and the code here is something simplified. If it looks like confusing, I will edit it.type(charlist[0]) is `string`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The issue is that you've got an unpicklable instance variable (`namelist`) in the `Book` instance. Because you're calling `pool.map` on an instance method, and you're running on Windows, the entire instance needs to be picklable in order for it to be passed to the child process. `Book.namelist` is a open file object (`_io.BufferedReader`), which can't be pickled. You can fix this a couple of ways. Based on the example code, it looks like you could just make `format_char` a top-level function:

```
def format_char(char):
    char = char + "a"
    return char


class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.namelist = arg

    def format_book(self):
        self.tempread = ""
        charlist = [f.read() for f in self.namelist] #list of char
        with Pool() as pool:
            txtlist = pool.map(format_char,charlist)
        self.tempread = "".join(txtlist)
        return self.tempread
```

However, if in reality, you need `format_char` to be an instance method, you can use [`__getstate__`/`__setstate__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) to make `Book` picklable, by removing the `namelist` argument from the instance before pickling it:

```
class Book(object):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.namelist = arg

    def __getstate__(self):
        """ This is called before pickling. """
        state = self.__dict__.copy()
        del state['namelist']
        return state

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        """ This is called while unpickling. """
        self.__dict__.update(state)

    def format_char(self,char):
        char = char + "a"

    def format_book(self):
        self.tempread = ""
        charlist = [f.read() for f in self.namelist] #list of char
        with Pool() as pool:
            txtlist = pool.map(self.format_char,charlist)
        self.tempread = "".join(txtlist)
        return self.tempread
```

This would be ok as long as you don't need to access `namelist` in the child process.

Comment: Thanks! It works well now, and my conjecture is wrong.

Comment: This is the real answer: self must be picklable.  For goodness sake, I searched way too long to get the unmistakably right answer.